# Не получается растянуть по высоте флекс-элемент внутри контейнера

Tags: css, flexbox

В данном коде есть чёрная рамка, внутри которой светло-зелёная рамка, внутри которой 2 флекс-элемента. Первый в виде текста стоит там где надо, а второй расположен по центру по горизонтали, а должен быть по горизонтали и вертикали одновременно, но justify-content: center; не работает(пометка: выравнивает по вертикали, потому что flex-direction: column;), потому что размер элемента ограничивается текстом, а должен быть во всё оставшееся пространство. Хочу отметить, что страница должна быть резиновой и не должно быть скроллинга. (overflow: hidden; запрещён)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Доп. задание 2.2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main3.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="one">
            <span class="bukva">М</span><b>ой дядя самых честных правил,</b><br />
                                     <i>Когда не в шутку занемог,</i><br />
                                     <ins>Он уважать себя заставил</ins><br />
                                     И лучше выдумать не мог
                <div class="onetwo">
                                    <span>
                                        <del>Его пример другим наука;</del><br />
                                        <sub>Но, боже мой, какая скука</sub><br />
                                        <sup>С больным сидеть</sup><br />
                                        <big>и день и ночь,</big><br />
                                        <small>Не отходя ни шагу прочь!</small>
                                    </span> 
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

````
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Comic Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/1999.ttf");
}
.one {
    border: 5px solid #92FF00;
    border-radius: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}
.bukva {
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F000FF;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 49px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.onetwo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.onetwo span {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Comic Sans";
    src: url("/fonts/1999.ttf");
}
.one {
    border: 5px solid #92FF00;
    border-radius: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.bukva {
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F000FF;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 49px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.onetwo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.onetwo span {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto auto;        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Доп. задание 2.2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main3.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="one">
          <div>
            <span class="bukva">М</span><b>ой дядя самых честных правил,</b><br />
                                     <i>Когда не в шутку занемог,</i><br />
                                     <ins>Он уважать себя заставил</ins><br />
                                     И лучше выдумать не мог
                                     </div>
                <div class="onetwo">
                                    <span>
                                        <del>Его пример другим наука;</del><br />
                                        <sub>Но, боже мой, какая скука</sub><br />
                                        <sup>С больным сидеть</sup><br />
                                        <big>и день и ночь,</big><br />
                                        <small>Не отходя ни шагу прочь!</small>
                                    </span> 
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "...а второй расположен по центру по горизонтали, а _должен быть по горизонтали и вертикали_ **одновременно**"

Comment: И где здесь решение? Элемент всё ещё не отцентрирован по вертикали

Comment: извиняюсь, исправил  стили

Comment: Теперь всё отлично! Ты спас мне жизнь.